# Importing a text file to create a list in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, quickdraw

I can't seem to figure out how to use values given in a text file and import them into python to create a list. What I'm trying to accomplish here is to create a gameboard and then put numbers on it as a sample set. I have to use Quickdraw to accomplish this - I kind of know how to get the numbers on Quickdraw but I cannot seem to import the numbers from the text file. Previous assignments involved getting the user to input values or using an I/O redirection, this is a little different. Could anyone assist me on this?

Comment: Look at the builtin [open](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#open) for starters

Comment: Show us what you've tried so that we can point out where you're going wrong

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. What exactly have you tried, and which part are you having a problem with implementing?

Comment: This is what I have so far then: 

    for i in range (0, Board_size):
     sys.stderr.write("Enter Game Values:")
     gamevalues = float(input()) # To get the values from the text file using I/O
     datalist = [gamevalues] # To define the values entered as a list
     print ("color 0 0 0")
     print (datalist)
     print ("fill text", x, y)

The quickdraw stuff I can work out, it is the list that is giving me nightmares.

Comment: You are allowed to edit your answer (there's a bit marked `edit` under the tags)- it makes it much easier for everyone to see your posted code, rather than in a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the contents of the file you want to read and output in the list you want to get.

```
# assuming you have values each on separate line
values = []
for line in open('path-to-the-file'):
    values.append(line)
    # might want to implement stripping newlines and such in here
    # by using line.strip() or .rstrip()

# or perhaps more than one value in a line, with some separator
values = []
for line in open('path-to-the-file'):
    # e.g. ':' as a separator
    separator = ':'
    line = line.split(separator)
    for value in line:
        values.append(value)

# or all in one line with separators
values = open('path-to-the-file').read().split(separator)
# might want to use .strip() on this one too, before split method
```

It could be more accurate if we knew the input and output requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Two steps here:

- [open](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#open) the file
- read the lines

This page might help you: http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects